# Getting error in nuxt application when trying to install the packages

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

On nuxt^2.16.3 I am trying to use node-16.20.1 but it's giving me error-

```
npm ERR! Override without name: nuxt/vue
```

But with v14.20.1 it is working.
Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?